# how to make sure item display cards have equal size all the time

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i'm working on a component where i need to display products in cards in a grid..but i keep having this problem where the size of individual cards (width or height) would be different from the other siblings based on the product's image or text in the card's body and so on..what's the best way to make sure that my cards have equal size all the time regardless of the content? i don't want to use static px sizing as it's not so responsive design friendly..
i want the card element to have a certain size while the children adjust according to that size, like images shrink or grow as needed, and texts wrap or have smaller font size when needed..i'm using bootstrap and some personal css in my project, my code looks like this:

css

```
.three-col-grid{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    row-gap: 15px;
}
```

JSX (react)

```
<div className="three-col-grid my-5">
    {products.map(product => {
        return <div className="d-inline-flex flex-column border border-2 border-main rounded shadow p-1 mx-3">
        <Link to={`/product/${id}`}><img src={img} className="image w-100" /></Link>
        <Link to={`/product/${id}`} className="text-decoration-none ">
            <div className="mx-1 my-4">
                <h4 className="text-start text-main">{title}</h4>
                <h5 className="text-start text-black">{price}</h5>
            </div>
        </Link>
        <ViewsRating views={views} rating={calcRating(ratingsNum, ratingsSum)} />
    </div>
    })}
</div>
```

i end up getting this in my website (forgive the image):
[image]

how do you guys handle displaying products and cards in your projects as to not have this issue? what is the best approach to have all cards maintain an equal size and still be responsive to screen size changes?

Comment: Are using React or Vue? HTML is not standard.

Comment: it's written above the code, it's jsx from react